How can I prevent backfeed to multiple AC motors connected to the same line?
I have 3-120vac motors that are connected together on one line. These motors move separate vents  simultaneously forwards and backwards. Each motor assembly has their own built in limit switch.
My problem is that the motors are not "perfectly" in sync with regards to their speed. As a result when one motor reaches it's limit switch and stops and if the other one or two motors have not stopped or reached their limit switches yet, the other one or two motors will back feed power through the neutral line to the stopped motor and cause the stopped motor to jump or twitch. Occasionally the stopped motor will jump or twitch past it's limit switch and cause the motor to start moving again. This has caused significant damage to the vents and the motors.
We've tried to add a separate limit switch to, we'll say to motor #1, in the line so if motor #1 reaches that limit switch then it just kills the power to all 3. This idea has also been proven to be ineffective. Again with the speed of each one being different, we find that one vent may not close completely or if motor #2 or #3 reach their limit switch prior to motor #1 reaching the separate switch we still get the jumping effect.
My question is, is there something that I could install in line or a way that I can prevent the backfeed to the other ac motors without having to put each motor on a separate line? These are automated controlled motors and the automation system uses relays for switching the direction voltage to the motors.Thanks for your time.

Can't the same control system also control a suitable DPDT relay (or contactor) to connect/disconnect each motor?

bit confused how the backfeeding works: doesn't the limit switch disconnect the phase? and isn't the neutral connector sufficiently grounded so that the potential on it is reliably enough at 0V?
